# how delete parent row with all child row from other table

Tags: php, mysql

```
parent_table
----------------------------------------------------------------------
id         name
1           a
2           b

child_table
---------------------------------------------------------------------
id        parent_table_id            name
1               1                      c
2               1                      d
3               1                      e
4               2                      f
5               2                      g
```

When I will delete first row from parent table then all child row of parent first row.
how is it possible??

Comment: do you want to delete the child rows if parent is delete??

Comment: use foreign key concept for that ..http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: What is your engine? let us show the table schema. If it is INODB, then it is possble.Otherwise you need to write using join or 2 queries.

Comment: Yes I want to delete all child of his parent row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [foreign keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

```sql
CREATE TABLE parent (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE child (
  id INT,
  parent_id INT,
  INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
  REFERENCES parent(id)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;


INSERT INTO parent VALUES (1), (2);
INSERT INTO child VALUES (1, 1);

# This query implicitly removes from `child` where parent_id = 1
DELETE FROM parent WHERE id = 1;
```

Answer (score 5):

Apart from `cascade delete`, you can use `join`, see example below:

```
DELETE parent_table, child_table 
FROM parent_table INNER JOIN child_table
  ON parent_table.id = child_table.parent_table_id
WHERE parent_table.id = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

While adding foreign key constraint use below options

```
ON DELETE  'CASCADE' 
ON UPDATE  'RESTRICT'
```

Now if you delete a parent row all associated child row will be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Define foreign keys with [cascading deletes](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/). Then when you delete the parent row, child row follows the same. [This](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/) tutorial will guide you through.

HINT: You need to add `ON DELETE CASCADE` in your child table upon creation

In your case:

```
CREATE TABLE parent_table(
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE child_table (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  parent_table_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY parent_table_id (parent_table_id),
  CONSTRAINT id_ibfk_1 
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_table_id) 
  REFERENCES parent_table (parent_table_id) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Now, your delete query:

```
DELETE FROM parent_table
WHERE id= 2
```

Your resultant data would be:

```
parent_table
----------------------------------------------------------------------
id         name
1           a

child_table
---------------------------------------------------------------------
id        parent_table_id            name
1               1                      c
2               1                      d
3               1                      e
```

**As requested in comments:**

You can see the explanation from [mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)

- *Key* - Synonym for Index
- *Constraint* - Foreign key constraint
- *References* - part of a foreign key constraint and it causes MySQL to require that the value(s) in the specified column(s) of the referencing table are also present in the specified column(s) of the referenced table.

**Updating existing table:**

```
ALTER TABLE child_table 
      ADD CONSTRAINT id_ibfk_1 
      FOREIGN KEY (parent_table_id) 
      REFERENCES parent_table (parent_table_id) 
      ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: please explain these portion of child table
  KEY parent_table_id (parent_table_id),
  CONSTRAINT id_ibfk_1 
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_table_id) 
  REFERENCES parent_table (parent_table_id)

Comment: Already I have existing child class. So how I can set key,constraint,references on manually
how is it possible??

Comment: Thank you too much @Thamizhan
May I get your social ID

Comment: @SalmanQuader Welcome! If it answered, don't forget to mark answered!

Comment: ALTER TABLE distribute_task 
      ADD CONSTRAINT id_ibfk_1 
      FOREIGN KEY (project_id) 
      REFERENCES project_list (id) 
      ON DELETE CASCADE
When I execute this code in sql then I get and sql erro
|Error
SQL query:

ALTER TABLE distribute_task 
      ADD CONSTRAINT id_ibfk_1 
      FOREIGN KEY (project_id) 
      REFERENCES project_list (id) 
      ON DELETE CASCADE

MySQL said: Documentation
#1005 - Can't create table `arenaco_login`.`#sql-aa0_4fd` (errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update") (Details…)
|
Why?

Answer (score 0):

For INODB: check thes link:[Cascading UPDATES and DELETES](https://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-enforcing-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: Just forward to home, please provide an updated link. Or even better, cite all the relevant information here.

Answer (score -1):

```
function delete($id){
$query = "DELETE FROM parent_table WHERE id = $id";
$query = "DELETE FROM child_table WHERE parent_table_id = $id";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
return true;
}
```

Comment: i need single query not multiple query